# How do I edit my css `toggle-slide` to work in two differents div?

Tags: css

I have a problem with a Toggle-Down Content made with only CSS.
I would like to put my trigger button and my content in two differents divs, and i don't know which selectors use. Here is the structure, I would like to have :

```
   <div class="row"> 
    <div class="col-md-12 button">
    <!-- My button--> 
    </div> 
    <div class="col-md-12 toggle-content">
    <!-- My content --> 
   </div>
```

And here is actually a snippet I have (it works actually but only if the toggle element is next to the input checkbox.

```css
input {
  display: none;
}

label {
  cursor: pointer;
  background: grey;
}

.test {
  -webkit-transition: height .3s ease;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 200px;
  background: lightgray;
}

#check:checked+.test {
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<label for="check">
  Click me
</label>
<input id="check" type="checkbox">
<div class="test">
  <p>Content</p>
</div>
```

Thanks a lot in advance if you can help and tell me what selectors or anything what to do ! Have a good day ! =)

Comment: would you be open to using Javascript? I don't think it's possible to control elements that are not next to each other or nested in a certain way using only CSS.

Comment: Oh okey, I know how to do it on Jquery, but I think it was possible on CSS too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some digging around I actually found a way to do this in CSS. As long as the element is within the same parent element it is possible to do this using the `~`selector. It searches for sibling elements inside the container.

```css
input {
  display: none;
}

label {
  cursor: pointer;
  background: grey;
}

.test {
  -webkit-transition: height .3s ease;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 200px;
  background: lightgray;
}

#check:checked ~.test {
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="someParent">
<input id="check" type="checkbox"><label for="check">
  Click me
</label>
<hr>
<div class="test">
  <p>Content</p>
</div>
</div>
```